# That topic is difficult to talk about

Tags: grammar, prepositions, word-order

While infinitive clauses don't have any noun before themselves, can they have any prepositions just as in the following examples?

- That topic is difficult to talk about.
- She is hard to be with.
- I love that car because it is safe to travel in. 
  So on.

What do you think?

Comment: **...don't have any noun before *them*** (not "themselves").

Answer (score 1):

The preposition at the end of your sentences is governed by the relationship of the specific verb in the infinitive clause to the subject.

> ... it is difficult to **talk** about.
>
> ...  she is hard to **be** with.
>
> ... that car because it is safe to **travel** in.

We talk *about* a topic (not along, with, onto, before, etc, a topic).

We travel *in* a car (not  onto a car, before a car,  etc)

So, as long as the preposition works with the underlying statement, it can appear at the end of such an infinitive clause which is part of the subject complement.

Comment: I see. So we can say that they don't need any nouns in order to function like this. Can we also use them for a purpose? 
Like "In order to talk about, we should find a topic which everyone here is interested in." ?

Comment: These prepositions do in fact need a noun; the noun is simply not in the immediate vicinity of the preposition; the preposition is part of the subject complement (the subject being the needed noun or NP): **it**, **she**, **that car**.

Comment: I think that a topic may be discussed, debated, or spoken on, rather than talked about. Am I mistaken?